# Is Here HD map live viewer available for non-paying customers?

Tags: here-api

Is there any way to browse the Here HD maps and find the **tile numbers** for a particular area around the GPS coordinate. I could not find the http address for Here **HD map viewer** tool. There are references to this tool in old documentation but I could not find it through google.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to have access on HD live map viewer for Freemium users. If the you are interested to get access to it, please contact us: https://developer.here.com/help#how-can-we-help-you